# How to kill mysql process through C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, mysql

I am getting "too many connections" problem in an Asp .Net Mvc application which get fix when i manually kill process through Mysql v6.56 IDE, But on remote hosting computer where i can't kill process each time how can i fix this error.

I have tried making a connection to `information_schema` DB's `PROCESSLIST` table but when connection is about to execute command there comes an error "access denied of root@loclahost information_schema". I also have tried to grant all privileges to root@loclahost but still i am not able to fix this problem. I have been coding the same way from last two years but in this application i am getting this problem i have use close each connection in every method. Please if some one have ever got this problem or know the answer.Please help me. Thanx in advance

Answer (score 3):

You need to close the connections from within your code, by calling close() on your connection Objects. Killing the threads through MySQL server is a horrible idea

Comment: because you may not always have access to mysql server, or the privileges to kill threads

Answer (score 0):

```
' code in vb.net you can convert it to c# easily
Dim ConnectionString As String = "your connection string"
Public Function KillAllMySQL() As Integer
    Dim query As String = "SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST"
    '
    Try
        Dim mySqlConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        ' 2. open connection to database using connectionString
        mySqlConnection.Open()
        ' 3. Create a command to hold values
        Dim objCmd As New MySqlCommand(query, mySqlConnection)
        ' 4. Add parameters for sqlCommand
        mySqlDataReader = objCmd.ExecuteReader()
        If mySqlDataReader.HasRows Then
            Do While mySqlDataReader.Read()
                ' kill processes with elapsed time > 200 seconds and in Sleep 
                If mySqlDataReader.GetInt32(5) > 200 And mySqlDataReader.GetString(4) = "Sleep" Then
                    KillMySqlProcess("KILL " & mySqlDataReader.GetInt32(0))
                End If
            Loop
        End If
        If Not mySqlDataReader Is Nothing Then mySqlDataReader.Close()
        If Not mySqlConnection Is Nothing Then mySqlConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Return -1
    End Try
    Return 0
End Function

Public Function KillMySqlProcess(ByVal myQuery As String) As Integer
    '1. Create a query
    Dim query As String = myQuery
    '
    Try
        Dim mySqlConnection As MySqlConnection = New MySqlConnection(ConnectionString)
        ' 2. open connection to database using connectionString
        mySqlConnection.Open()
        ' 3. Create a command to hold values
        Dim objCmd As New MySqlCommand(query, mySqlConnection)
        objCmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        mySqlConnection.Close()
    Catch ex As MySqlException
        Return -1
    End Try

    Return 0
End Function
```

Comment: Some more explanation what your code does and how, would be nice.

Comment: Explanation, Why it reads like it is plain English to me. However, it still a bad idea to kill open connections at the server level, especially if there are many users.